# App does not have permission to make this call

Tags: javascript, facebook-opengraph

Even if i give all the permission (from "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/") for my app to make a call , returned error says "App does not have permission to make this call" for an "Unlike" call. My request is below in JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    UnLike("598330036881973");
});
function UnLike(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/likes?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAEKjZCFGXGFK1uzVRsx5RZBc8lwXZA9kgnAq8ahGBKX0oIUZB0UH20m1quLukJOFOQS6PBFzGxI43QP3zpxgGWRgtoUTZADZBnkGo0HsvRry0YLnZAbsxG30XihcVQ1OHNKflOTFOjwmgaVuQdSVZCBMPRFfxsQ4Y9evjX0TqFR7Pj3GYK9c2gX4uZBvwN0VLagZDZD',
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            document.write(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

What do you think the problem is? Is unliking using the OpenGraph API forbidden?

Comment: Could you reformat you code? It's not really readable.

Comment: Facebook pages can not be liked via API, and not unliked either. The Like button social plugin is the only way to do that apart from the button on facebook.com itself).